# How do I unmount a div generated by a loop using id's in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unmount

I want to be able to close the box(div) by using generated id's. I am confused as to what exactly should be inside .unmountComponentAtNode(HERE)

I've tried < div id={i} style={divStyle}>
    in the return statement of Box and assigning it in the loop, but neither have worked.[image]

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Box = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById(i);
  },

  render: function() {
    var divStyle = {
      textAlign: "center",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      border: "solid",
      borderRadius: 2,
      color: "#999999",
      width: 250,
      height: 100,
      display: "inline-block",
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      margin: 10,
      padding: 40
    };

    var buttonStyle = {
      float: "right",
      marginTop: -30,
      marginRight: -30,
      cursor: "crosshair",
      color: "#F00",
      border: "1px solid #AEAEAE",
      borderRadius: 30,
      background: "#FFF",
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: "bold",
      display: "inline-block"
    };

    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} style={buttonStyle}>x</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ShowBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    var boxes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

    var renderData = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      var box = boxes[i];
      renderData.push(<Box id={i} key={i + box} />);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {renderData}
      </div>
        );
      }
    });

module.exports = ShowBox;
```

Comment: You are missing closing bracket for `unmountComponentAtNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the boxes `array` in `state` variable, and create the Box using `map`, pass a function from Parent component to child component to delete that component `onClick` of close button.

**Issue** with the way you are doing is, if you `unmount` that component by `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById(i);`, it will again get created because components are created by the `array` and you didn't change the `array`, that item still present in `array`, so it will not work, you need to store the `array` in `state` and delete the entry of that element from `array` in order to see the changes in `UI`.

One more thing, since you are using the common `style` for all the components so instead of storing that in variable inside `render`, store it globally and use it, **it will avoid the same `styling` variable creation multiple times and make the code more readable and compact**.

Write it like this:

```js
var colors = ["#393E41", "#E94F37", "#1C89BF", "#A1D363", "#85FFC7", "#297373", "#FF8552", "#A40E4C", "#33FF00"];

var divStyle = {
      textAlign: "center",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      border: "solid",
      borderRadius: 2,
      color: "#999999",
      width: 25,
      height: 20,
      display: "inline-block",
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      margin: 10,
      padding: 40
    };

var buttonStyle = {
      float: "right",
      marginTop: -30,
      marginRight: -30,
      cursor: "crosshair",
      color: "#F00",
      border: "1px solid #AEAEAE",
      borderRadius: 30,
      background: "#FFF",
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: "bold",
      display: "inline-block"
    };

var Box = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {   
       this.props.deleteElement(this.props.id);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div style={Object.assign({},divStyle,{backgroundColor:colors[this.props.name]})}>
        {this.props.name}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} style={buttonStyle}>x</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ShowBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
         boxes : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
     }
  },
  deleteElement: function(i){
     let boxes = this.state.boxes.slice();
     boxes.splice(i, 1);
     this.setState({boxes});
  },
  renderData(){
     return this.state.boxes.map((box,i)=>{
        return <Box id={i} name={box} key={i} deleteElement={this.deleteElement}/>
     })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
           <div>
              {this.renderData()}
           </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<ShowBox/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: facing any issue in this ?

Comment: deleteElement basically just pops off the last box of the array, not the actual box I click "x" on. Other than that it's good!

Comment: no its not, you might get confused because i was using array indexes to display inside box, instead of values, now check the updated answer, you will see only clicked item will get deleted :) let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: I have colored the boxes using an array of different colors. Clicking on the First box closes the last box still. I think the problem is in `boxes.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: how you are assigning the color from color array ?

Comment: right under `boxes` i have `colors: ["#393E41", "#E94F37", "#1C89BF", "#A1D363", "#85FFC7", "#297373", "#FF8552", "#A40E4C", "#33FF00"]` then I added `bgColor={this.state.colors[i]}` to <Box /> in renderData()s return statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139170/discussion-between-reality-is-a-fractal-and-mayank-shukla).